# binding a combox in runtime by data from another runtime combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 combobox create in runtime. The first one is binding to a sql query, but the second one would be binding to a sql query which has as constraint the value choose in the first combobox. Now i need a idea to implement this! When i change the state of first combo box the second combo box have to update his elememts.

Comment: could you please the code which you tried sofar?

Comment: there isn't code yet. i have to create 2 combo box bilding to sql query.the first combobox define the id of category for the second query(to populate the second combobox). eachone of combo box is create in runtime mode and the query are defined by a xml file.i read xml file and import the query and a tag for the construct "where" of second query.thx